# How to find the token (phrase, word), not the sequence of characters in Django text data model

Tags: python, django, postgresql

In Django data model, Consider that we have a text like this:

```
I am going to go somewhere.
```

If I use the `Entity.objects.filter(column__contains="go")`, it will return `going` word as well. But I only want the `go` word to be returned.

Is there any solution other than using `Full Text Search`?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the queryset and then return entries with the word in the string. Try something like this:

```
for entry in entries:
   if 'go' in entry.column:
      return True
   else:
      return False
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I am searching for the keyword twice, and I guess it won't scale. On the other hand,  after implementing this method, I keep getting this error `Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.` This answer didn't solve my problem, but It could be a solution for similar cases. [up]

Comment: For those who may be interested, my code according to Joshlsullivan's answer is:
`to_be_deleted = []
for entry in entries:
    if 'go' not in entry.column:
        to_be_deleted.append(entry .id)  
entries.exclude(id__in=to_be_deleted)
`

Comment: @MehrdadSalimi it's possible to use regex with the ORM - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex

Answer (score 0):

After checking the Regex document for Django (thanks to Joshlsullivan), This solution worked for me.

```
result = Entry.objects.filter(text__regex=rf"(\s){searched}(\s)" )
```

In my case, `searched` is a variable and changes over time (It is not always the word `go` as in my question). Using `{}` I was able to add a variable to the regex string. `\s` means white space.